# Connect SAP System

Tags: java, jco

I am working in a Java EE project that integrates with SAP system, and I am trying to run a simple standalone Java class that calls a RFC. My snippet of code is

```
JCO.Client mConnection =
    JCO.createClient("dummy", // SAP client
             "dummy", // userid
             "dummy", // password
                 "dummy", // language (null for the default language)
                 "dummy", // application server host name
                 "dummy"); // system number
```

It throws the following exception

> JCO.classInitialize(): Could not load middleware layer 'com.sap.mw.jco.rfc.MiddlewareRFC'
>
> JCO.nativeInit(): Could not initialize dynamic link library sapjcorfc

The only library that I have in this moment is `sapjco.jar`, I have seen in some forums that I need this two libraries (`librfc32.dll`, `sapjcorfc.dll`) to be able to run this code in an standalone application.

Is that right? Where can I get these two libraries? The last one is to put in the same folder than the `sapjco.jar`, is that ok too?

If I cannot run this in my local computer I will have to deploy the application every time that I want to test it :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on which JCo version you use (you didn't state that), you need one or two platform-specific native libraries. They come bundled with the JCo package, along with some installation documentation. If you don't have this, you've got an incomplete and probably illegal package (redistribution is not allowed). Go to http://service.sap.com/connectors and get the valid one.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that for this link one needs an SAP Service Marketplace user with authorizations to download files. That is why people are looking for the libraries in the other places. I have never understood this SAP decision but this is how it looks like right now.

Comment: @Jagger The rationale behind this decision is that this is a critical library from a security POV and SAP wants to keep a tight control on the versions that are shipped - that is, stop some of the questionable sites out there from shipping older, flawed versions. I don't agree with this policy, but that's the official reason.